# Fans always ON and overheating on DELL XPS 15 9570 with NVIDIA GPU enabled

Tags: nvidia, dell, overheating, fan, xps

I have Ubuntu 19.04 on my DELL XPS 15 9570, with the 5.0.0-15-generic kernel version. This laptop has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti GPU and all the time the fans are on around 3200/3700 RPM.

If I switch on Intel (Power saving mode) with PRIME Profiles of NVIDIA X Server Settings, the problem disappears and the fans turn around 0/2500 RPM.

How can I solve this problem? I don't want to bypass my NVIDIA GPU.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not a problem to be solved, it's how it is. That said the UEFI can be acting in an overzealous manner when running with the Nvidia graphics. An UEFI update may or may not improve it.

Comment: So, I have to wait a BIOS update?

Comment: Maybe there's one already. Check Dell's page.

Answer (score 1):

That problem can't be solved unfortunately. The Dell XPS 9570 BIOS was updated a long time ago in a way that forces the fans to always spin when the NVIDIA card is powered on. On Linux, when the nvidia module is loaded, the card will always be active, and so the fans.

This a problem with Dell XPS 9570, other laptops such as 9560 with same exact operating system and settings don't have this issue, because they are running a different firmware. Since Dell added that feature with an update, I don't reckon they'll ever change it, and it's not possible to rollback to an earlier version because it's not allowed.

Source: I own that laptop and I've worked on adding support for Dell XPS 9570 to [nvidia-xrun](https://github.com/Witko/nvidia-xrun), also there are different articles and forums online mentioning this peculiarity of the Dell XPS 9570 with BIOS version >= 1.7.0

See https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/akngpy/incompetent_dell_devs_answer_to_bios_170_fan/