# Dell XPS 15 7590 Heat problem

Tags: dell, overheating, xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 7590 and wondered if there were other people who had problems with the computer getting incredibly hot some times.

Are there things I can do to prevent it from warming up? Actually, the computer has always had this problem, only now it's much worse than before

[image: Temperature when the computer is just running Brave (webbrowser)]

Comment: Sounds like you have  Dell from Hell. This is a known problem with your machine. Read here https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-7590-Thermal-concerns/td-p/7476496 and also here https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/Dell-XPS-13-Fan-and-Heat-problem/td-p/4098333 (that one is funny). I would say it is conformed by the community here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144018/fans-always-on-and-overheating-on-dell-xps-15-9570-with-nvidia-gpu-enabled

Answer (score -1):

If over heating is repeatedly happening, for 90% it means you have a malware consuming most of your comp ressources and results in a considerable over heating. Run malware scan with malwarebyte or eset internet security which I trust the most for its advanced AI detection. The scan should be done offline to avoid malware connection to its server. Another way to check this out, is to use your comp offline(not attached to network) : lauch 3 heavy softwares and let your comp running for 1 hour. If its not over heated, then its a 100% sign of malware. Else, it could be that your comp fan flooded with dust and not running any more, you have to clean it. If you do not have the requested knowledge to do it by your self, I advise you to bring it to IT repairing store.